# SwiftUI not dismissing keyboard correctly after navigating away

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, keyboard

I'm having problems with SwiftUI when going up a level in the navigation stack if keyboard was showing when I last left it.

1. In the first screen, focus on a text field and keyboard shows up
2. Trigger a navigation link to show a second view in the navigation stack
3. Tap back to go back to the first view

Expected: keyboard should either be still shown or dismissed, all controls on the screen should be responsive as programmed

Observed: keyboard is not shown, but lower half of the screen is unresponsive as if keyboard is still there blocking tap inputs

Specifically to trigger it in the sample code below:

1. Focus on the search field to show the keyboard
2. Tap any link, e.g. "Row 0"
3. Tap "Back"

Observed: "safeAreaInset bottom" view is moved to middle of the screen. The area below that is not responding to taps.

Tested on: Xcode 14.1, iOS 16.1, solution needs to support iOS 15.0

[image]

```
struct KeyboardDismissSampleView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch
    
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @State var showDetailView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $showDetailView) {
                    Text("showDetailView")
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { i in
                        
                        // Version A
//                        NavigationLink {
//                            Text("Row \(i)")
//                        } label: {
//                            Text("Row \(i)")
//                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
//                        }
                        
                        // Version B
                        Button("Row \(i)") {
//                            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            dismissSearch()
                            showDetailView = true
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, content: {
                // This view is just to visually show the issue
                // Even without his safeAreaInset section, the area covered by the keyboard is still not responding to taps
                Text("safeAreaInset bottom")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            })
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use resignFirstResponder and dismissSearch, and they either have the same problem or introduce other problems. This log is shown in the Xcode console and apparently you can't dismiss keyboard and navigate at the same time:

`pushViewController:animated: called on <_TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext_ 0x10f01c600> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.`

I have looked at these related questions:

[Keyboard dismiss not working properly when dismiss the view swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267644/keyboard-dismiss-not-working-properly-when-dismiss-the-view-swiftui)

[Keyboard not dismissing in SwiftUI with onTapGesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165703/keyboard-not-dismissing-in-swiftui-with-ontapgesture)

[SwiftUI: dismiss List searchable keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130303/swiftui-dismiss-list-searchable-keyboard)

Comment: There was a deleted answer that suggested using FocusState and setting it to nil before navigating away. I have tested and if it's a TextField it would indeed work.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715792 still not fixed...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.endEditing(true)
```

resolves the problem, although it does generate a deprecation warning.

Note that I removed commented out code and replace the `NavigationView` with the new `NavigationStack`, but that wasn't what fixed it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { i in
                        Button("Row \(i)") {
                            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.endEditing(true)
                            path.append(i)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                Text("show detail view")
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                Text("safeAreaInset bottom")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. It does work on iOS 16. Sorry I forgot to mention that I need to support iOS 15.0. I have tried keeping NavigationView and just changed the button action to `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.endEditing(true); showDetailView = true`. But I'm having the same issues as using `UIResponder.resignFirstResponder`? Does that work for you?

Comment: It looks like it _does_ need the new `NavigationStack` to work - I tried it with `NavigationView` and it doesn't push on the new view when the search field is active.

Comment: Same problem here. I want to support from iOS 14.0 and that makes it more difficult.

It solved some issues from me to make a custom View that use rather a NavigationView or NavigationStack depending of version. But the navigation still won't open when keyboard is present. I was trying to implement NavigationPath published properties inside a ObservableObject but I could't make it work with a lower version of iOS 16. Event using available or unavailable marks.

Any help?